# “这个是我常用的资料夹” equals “This is my frequently used folders” or "This is my favorite folder"?

Tags: translation

Should I translate “This is my frequently used folders” or "This is my favorite folder" as "这个是我常用的资料夹"?
Is it normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would translate "This is my frequently used folders."to "这个是我常用的资料夹。"

Because "frequently used" exactly means "常用的", while "favorite" is more like "最喜欢的"。

Answer (score 0):

I would translate

"This is my frequently used folders."

to

These are my frequently-used folders.
这些是我经常使用的文件夹。

or

这个是我常用的资料夹。
This is the folder I use the most.